# Sonata FormMapper adding link from integer field

Tags: php, mysql, entity, sonata-admin

Been trying to add a element to a table row, this element is an ID from a table and its defined as integer. When I add it to FormMapper it shows is as a integer field. I would like to show it as a button to edit that location on another page.

Here is a snippet of MB/SiteBundle/Admin/LocationAdmin.php

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
 $id = $this->getSubject()->getId(); 

 $options = array('required' => false);
 $options['help'] = '<a href="/admin/mb/site/location/' . $id. '/edit">';

$formMapper
  ->add('year')
  ->add('duns_number')
  ->add('address_1')
  ->add('address_2')
  ->add('city')
  ->add('state')
  ->add('zip')
  ->add('type')
  ->add('isPrimary', null, array('required' => false))
  ->add('numEmployees')
  ->add('numCoveredEmployees')
  ->add('benefitOption')
  ->add('freeformBenefit1', null, array('label' => "benefit_4c_description"))
  ->add('freeformBenefit2', null, array('label' => "benefit_4c_whyappropriate"))

  ->add('id', null, $options)
  ->end()

  ->with('Contact Info')
    ->add('cbc', 'sonata_type_admin', array('delete' => false, 'label' => false, 'required' => false, 'btn_add' => false))
  ->end()
  ;
}
```

Now below is a snippet of MB/SiteBundle/Entity/Location.php

```
/**
* @var integer
*
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
private $id;
```

On the last td of the row table would like to see a link to location page as on the help property i stated. thx

Comment: Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Rendering a button is easy, but it will trigger your form instead of redirecting to the new page (the latter breaks UX, since buttons are a call-to-action, not a link).

### using custom buttons

You'll need to create a custom FormType and render your custom button (as `<a/>`, instead of `<button/>`). Then you can easily set the desired URL and render it.

### using built-in behaviour

An alternative way (if the Entities know each other and there is an Admin registered for it): use `sonata_type_model_list`

```
$formMapper
    ->add('location', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('btn_add' => false, 'btn_delete' => false);
```

This won't render a button, but renders Sonata's list-element for references which is clickable too.